# Texlive installation from Medium Scheme to Full Scheme

Tags: texlive

I installed Texlive with Medium Scheme. Now want to add all the packages to the Full Scheme instead of adding packages one by one.  How shall I proceed?

Comment: Did you try to install the `scheme-full` package? I can't easily test it, but after a quick look at the documentation it should work.

Answer (score 2):

You can list the texlive package schemes using

```bash
tlmgr info schemes
```

Then use `tlmgr install` to install your desired scheme. For example, to install the full scheme, do

```bash
tlmgr install scheme-full
```

You can also view and install specific collections. For example,

```bash
# view collections
tlmgr info collections
# install a collection
tlmgr install collection-mathscience
```

You can list the collections in a scheme and the packages in a collection using

```bash
tlmgr info --list scheme-basic
tlmgr info --list collection-mathscience
```

I suggest you look at the collections in `scheme-full` before installing because you may not need some of them (e.g. language collections).

Reference: https://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/tlmgr.html